# Scraping fanduel sportsbook for odds with Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So i'm very new to web scraping with python and I have a question regarding a project i'm working on. I'm attempting to implement a betting strategy based off of something called the kelly criterion. In a nutshell, it asserts that there is an optimal fixed fraction (f) of your starting bankroll to bet based on the expected value (EV) of a bet in order to maximize growth.

EV = (b*p - a*q)

f =  EV / [b*a]

Optimal_Bet = f*C

Where,

b = potential units won

a = potential units lost (while accounting for "vigorish")

p = Team 1 win probability

q = Team 2 win probability

C = Initial bankroll before bet

b,a are based off of the odds that the sportsbook offers. Approximating p,q of a given team is a separate challenge.

I already have a function that takes in C and the odds in American format of a particular matchup (ex. +102 & -120) and calculates b,a,EV,f, and the Optimal_Bet. 
I would like to scrape the sportsbook I use (fanduel) for all the betting lines in a particular sport, and feed them into the function in real time in order to spit out EV,f, and the corresponding optimal bet for each matchup.

Finally, my problem is that when I request the content from the website and create a soup object, it doesn't seem to be getting everything out of the html document.

Here is my python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fanduel_nfl_response = requests.get('https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/sports/navigation/6227.1/11147.3')
fanduel_nba_response = requests.get('https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/sports/navigation/830.1/8047.1')
fanduel_cbb_response = requests.get('https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/sports/navigation/11086.3/11087.3')

fanduel_nfl_page = fanduel_nfl_response.content
fanduel_nba_page = fanduel_nba_response.content
fanduel_cbb_page = fanduel_cbb_response.content

nfl_soup = BeautifulSoup(fanduel_nfl_page,"lxml")
nba_soup = BeautifulSoup(fanduel_nba_page, "lxml")
cbb_soup = BeautifulSoup(fanduel_cbb_page, "lxml")

print(nba_soup)
```

When I print either of the three soup objects, I get an output that does not seem to contain any of the information I want, even though i'm certain the website links I chose are correct. So I can't use .find_all() to search for anything because it's just not there. [Here is a picture of what the nba line page looks like when I inspect it in chrome. The line highlighted in blue as well as the five lines below it contain the information that I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo0dI.jpg)

[Here is a picture of the output to my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZOsb.jpg)

Is there a reason why my content request isn't getting the whole html document, or am I missing something entirely? Am I actually getting all the content with my request and the stuff I want is just not visible? I am very new to this so any responses would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the page is dynamic. You need to scrape either using Selenium, or looking in the Network tab for the XHR (dev tools)

Comment: So i've learned, thanks!

Comment: @rl-pdg - have you been able to update your code to use Selenium now that pages are dynamic? Do you have any examples of how you scraped the data?

Answer (score 4):

So you can get the XHR rquest url by looking at the Dev Tools -> Network tab -> XHR.

It'll return a json structure (which is nested) so you'll have to parse it some way (which I did in the function). It just grabs everything, so if you want specific columns, you can just filter out what you need from the dataframes:

Just remember me when you become a millionaire ;-)...

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from functools import reduce


def parse_data(jsonData):
    results_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for alpha in jsonData['events']:
        print ('Gathering %s data: %s @ %s' %(alpha['sportname'],alpha['participantname_away'],alpha['participantname_home']))
        alpha_df = json_normalize(alpha).drop('markets',axis=1)
        for beta in alpha['markets']:
            beta_df = json_normalize(beta).drop('selections',axis=1)
            beta_df.columns = [str(col) + '.markets' for col in beta_df.columns]
            for theta in beta['selections']:
                theta_df = json_normalize(theta)
                theta_df.columns = [str(col) + '.selections' for col in theta_df.columns]

                temp_df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right, left_index=True, right_index=True), [alpha_df, beta_df, theta_df])
                results_df = results_df.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

    return results_df




jsonData_fanduel_nfl = requests.get('https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/cache/psmg/UK/57494.3.json').json()
jsonData_fanduel_nba = requests.get('https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/cache/psmg/UK/55978.3.json').json()
jsonData_fanduel_cbb = requests.get('https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/cache/psmg/UK/53474.3.json').json()


nfl = parse_data(jsonData_fanduel_nfl)
nba = parse_data(jsonData_fanduel_nba)
cbb = parse_data(jsonData_fanduel_cbb)
```

**Output:**

```
print (nba.head(10).to_string())
   BB.markets awaypitchername awayscoreline big3markettype.markets competitorcode.selections competitornumber.selections                       csvavailablebettypes.markets csvpricetypes.markets ctag.markets  currentewplaceterms.markets  currentewreduction.markets currenthandicap.selections currentmatchhandicap.markets currentmatchhandicap.selections  currentpricedown.selections  currentpriceup.selections currentscore.selections derivativetypes.markets estimatepricedown.selections estimatepriceup.selections eventlistcode                               eventname                       eventname.markets ewfactor.selections                     externaldescription  fosportinternalorder.markets gameperiod.markets gameperiodname.markets hadvalue.selections homepitchername homescoreline idfobolifestate.selections  idfoevent  idfoevent.markets idfohadtype.markets  idfomarket.markets  idfomarket.selections idfomarketlinetype.markets idfomarketsubjecttype.markets  idfomarkettype.markets  idfomarkettypeclass.markets idfomeeting idfoparticipant.selections  idfoparticipant_away  idfoparticipant_home  idfoselection.selections idfoselectionsuspensiontype.selections   idfosport idfosporttype.markets idfosporttype.selections idfotemplateselection.selections  internalorder  internalorder.markets  internalorder.selections iscurrentlistoffer.selections  islive  ismainoutright.markets  ismatch  ismatchhandicaptype.markets  isoutright.markets  israce  istradable  istradable.markets  istrapbettingoptionon.markets  isunderover.markets jockeyname.selections jockeysilks.selections listcode.selections listsubcode.selections lowerband.selections marketinternaldescription.markets     mtag.markets                    name.markets      name.selections nontradableon.selections  noofmarkets participantname_away participantname_home pitcherhacode.markets  price.selections resultpositionfinal.selections  selectionhashcode.selections selexternaldescription.selections shortname.selections sportname sppricedown.selections sppriceup.selections teletextname.selections              tsstart      tsstart.markets ttagleft.markets ttagright.markets upperband.selections
0       False            None          None                     TP                      None                        None  A,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8...                CP,SGM         None                          1.0                         1.0                      215.5                        215.5                           215.5                         23.0                       20.0                    None                    HP,O                         None                       None     1771|1772  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                None  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                             3                 1+             Game Lines                   U            None          None                          N   795248.3           795248.3                  OU          30740246.3             30740246.3                      TOTAL                          None                 45773.1                       4778.1        None                       None             1912153.3             1912141.3               106258137.3                                   None  BASKETBALL            BASKETBALL               BASKETBALL                             None             10                   5002                        20                          None    True                   False     True                         True               False   False        True                True                          False                 True                  None                   None                None                   None                 None                              None  E795248.3|SCORE  Total Points (half-point line)                Under                     None          287      Detroit Pistons  Cleveland Cavaliers                  None          1.869565                           None                         29505                              None                Under       NBA                   None                 None                   Under  2020-01-07T19:10:00  2020-01-07T19:10:00             None              None                 None
1       False            None          None                     TP                      None                        None  A,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8...                CP,SGM         None                          1.0                         1.0                      215.5                        215.5                           215.5                         21.0                       20.0                    None                    HP,O                         None                       None     1771|1772  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                None  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                             3                 1+             Game Lines                   O            None          None                          N   795248.3           795248.3                  OU          30740246.3             30740246.3                      TOTAL                          None                 45773.1                       4778.1        None                       None             1912153.3             1912141.3               106258175.3                                   None  BASKETBALL            BASKETBALL               BASKETBALL                             None             10                   5002                        10                          None    True                   False     True                         True               False   False        True                True                          False                 True                  None                   None                None                   None                 None                              None  E795248.3|SCORE  Total Points (half-point line)                 Over                     None          287      Detroit Pistons  Cleveland Cavaliers                  None          1.952381                           None                          6650                              None                 Over       NBA                   None                 None                    Over  2020-01-07T19:10:00  2020-01-07T19:10:00             None              None                 None
2       False            None          None                     PS                      None                        None  A,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8...                    CP         None                          1.0                         1.0                          3                            3                               3                         11.0                       10.0                    None                    H,HP                         None                       None     1771|1772  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                None  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                             3                 1+             Game Lines                   H            None          None                          N   795248.3           795248.3                  HA          30740333.3             30740333.3                       SIDE                          None                 45778.1                       4777.1        None                1.92111e+06             1912153.3             1912141.3               106259029.3                                   None  BASKETBALL            BASKETBALL               BASKETBALL                             None             10                      2                      1010                          None    True                   False     True                         True               False   False        True                True                          False                False                  None                   None                None                   None                 None                              None  E795248.3|SCORE                  Spread Betting  Cleveland Cavaliers                     None          287      Detroit Pistons  Cleveland Cavaliers                  None          1.909091                           None                         47283                              None            Cleveland       NBA                   None                 None     Cleveland Cavaliers  2020-01-07T19:10:00  2020-01-07T19:10:00             None              None                 None
3       False            None          None                     PS                      None                        None  A,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8...                    CP         None                          1.0                         1.0                          3                            3                               3                         11.0                       10.0                    None                    H,HP                         None                       None     1771|1772  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                None  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                             3                 1+             Game Lines                   A            None          None                          N   795248.3           795248.3                  HA          30740333.3             30740333.3                       SIDE                          None                 45778.1                       4777.1        None                1.92113e+06             1912153.3             1912141.3               106259067.3                                   None  BASKETBALL            BASKETBALL               BASKETBALL                             None             10                      2                        10                          None    True                   False     True                         True               False   False        True                True                          False                False                  None                   None                None                   None                 None                              None  E795248.3|SCORE                  Spread Betting      Detroit Pistons                     None          287      Detroit Pistons  Cleveland Cavaliers                  None          1.909091                           None                           987                              None            Detroit P       NBA                   None                 None         Detroit Pistons  2020-01-07T19:10:00  2020-01-07T19:10:00             None              None                 None
4       False            None          None                     PS                      None                        None  A,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8...                CP,SGM         None                          1.0                         1.0                        3.5                          3.5                             3.5                         23.0                       20.0                    None                    H,HP                         None                       None     1771|1772  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                None  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                             3                 1+             Game Lines                   H            None          None                          N   795248.3           795248.3                  HA          30740357.3             30740357.3                       SIDE                          None                 45778.1                       4777.1        None                1.92111e+06             1912153.3             1912141.3               106259194.3                                   None  BASKETBALL            BASKETBALL               BASKETBALL                             None             10                   5001                      1010                          None    True                   False     True                         True               False   False        True                True                          False                False                  None                   None                None                   None                 None                              None  E795248.3|SCORE        Spread (half-point line)  Cleveland Cavaliers                     None          287      Detroit Pistons  Cleveland Cavaliers                  None          1.869565                           None                         44903                              None            Cleveland       NBA                   None                 None     Cleveland Cavaliers  2020-01-07T19:10:00  2020-01-07T19:10:00             None              None                 None
5       False            None          None                     PS                      None                        None  A,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8...                CP,SGM         None                          1.0                         1.0                        3.5                          3.5                             3.5                         21.0                       20.0                    None                    H,HP                         None                       None     1771|1772  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                None  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                             3                 1+             Game Lines                   A            None          None                          N   795248.3           795248.3                  HA          30740357.3             30740357.3                       SIDE                          None                 45778.1                       4777.1        None                1.92113e+06             1912153.3             1912141.3               106259237.3                                   None  BASKETBALL            BASKETBALL               BASKETBALL                             None             10                   5001                        10                          None    True                   False     True                         True               False   False        True                True                          False                False                  None                   None                None                   None                 None                              None  E795248.3|SCORE        Spread (half-point line)      Detroit Pistons                     None          287      Detroit Pistons  Cleveland Cavaliers                  None          1.952381                           None                         42219                              None            Detroit P       NBA                   None                 None         Detroit Pistons  2020-01-07T19:10:00  2020-01-07T19:10:00             None              None                 None
6        True            None          None                     ML                      None                        None  A,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8...                CP,SGM         None                          1.0                         1.0                       None                         None                            None                         25.0                       33.0                    None                    None                         None                       None     1771|1772  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                None  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                             3                 1+             Game Lines                   H            None          None                          N   795248.3           795248.3                  HA          30740385.3             30740385.3                      MONEY                          None                  4937.1                       3842.1        None                1.92111e+06             1912153.3             1912141.3               106259265.3                                   None  BASKETBALL            BASKETBALL               BASKETBALL                             None             10                      1                      1010                          None    True                   False     True                        False               False   False        True                True                          False                False                  None                   None                None                   None                 None                              None  E795248.3|SCORE                       Moneyline  Cleveland Cavaliers                     None          287      Detroit Pistons  Cleveland Cavaliers                  None          2.320000                           None                         23349                              None            Cleveland       NBA                   None                 None     Cleveland Cavaliers  2020-01-07T19:10:00  2020-01-07T19:10:00             None              None                 None
7        True            None          None                     ML                      None                        None  A,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8...                CP,SGM         None                          1.0                         1.0                       None                         None                            None                         39.0                       25.0                    None                    None                         None                       None     1771|1772  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                None  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                             3                 1+             Game Lines                   A            None          None                          N   795248.3           795248.3                  HA          30740385.3             30740385.3                      MONEY                          None                  4937.1                       3842.1        None                1.92113e+06             1912153.3             1912141.3               106259271.3                                   None  BASKETBALL            BASKETBALL               BASKETBALL                             None             10                      1                        10                          None    True                   False     True                        False               False   False        True                True                          False                False                  None                   None                None                   None                 None                              None  E795248.3|SCORE                       Moneyline      Detroit Pistons                     None          287      Detroit Pistons  Cleveland Cavaliers                  None          1.641026                           None                         16669                              None            Detroit P       NBA                   None                 None         Detroit Pistons  2020-01-07T19:10:00  2020-01-07T19:10:00             None              None                 None
8       False            None          None                     PS                      None                        None  A,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8...                    CP         None                          1.0                         1.0                        1.5                          1.5                             1.5                         28.0                       25.0                    None                    None                         None                       None     1771|1772  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                None  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                             3                1-2               1st Half                   H            None          None                          N   795248.3           795248.3                  HA          30740405.3             30740405.3                       SIDE                          None                 47598.1                       5303.1        None                       None             1912153.3             1912141.3               106259531.3                                   None  BASKETBALL            BASKETBALL               BASKETBALL                             None             10                    202                      1010                          None    True                   False     True                         True               False   False        True                True                          False                False                  None                   None                None                   None                 None                              None  E795248.3|SCORE                 1st Half Spread  Cleveland Cavaliers                     None          287      Detroit Pistons  Cleveland Cavaliers                  None          1.892857                           None                         30949                              None            Cleveland       NBA                   None                 None     Cleveland Cavaliers  2020-01-07T19:10:00  2020-01-07T19:10:00             None              None                 None
9       False            None          None                     PS                      None                        None  A,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8...                    CP         None                          1.0                         1.0                        1.5                          1.5                             1.5                         27.0                       25.0                    None                    None                         None                       None     1771|1772  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                None  Detroit Pistons At Cleveland Cavaliers                             3                1-2               1st Half                   A            None          None                          N   795248.3           795248.3                  HA          30740405.3             30740405.3                       SIDE                          None                 47598.1                       5303.1        None                       None             1912153.3             1912141.3               106259532.3                                   None  BASKETBALL            BASKETBALL               BASKETBALL                             None             10                    202                        10                          None    True                   False     True                         True               False   False        True                True                          False                False                  None                   None                None                   None                 None                              None  E795248.3|SCORE                 1st Half Spread      Detroit Pistons                     None          287      Detroit Pistons  Cleveland Cavaliers                  None          1.925926                           None                         13664                              None            Detroit P       NBA                   None                 None         Detroit Pistons  2020-01-07T19:10:00  2020-01-07T19:10:00             None              None                 None
```

Comment: Awesome, much appreciated!

Comment: @rlando, if this helped you out, be sure to accept the solution

Comment: How did you find those json links on the website? I see nothing in the XHR

Comment: I believe it was their old api so you used to be able to see it in the xhr. So now they don’t make requests with it, but apparently it still works with the right parameters.