# Scraping fanduel with BeautifulSoup, can't find values visible in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape lines for a typical baseball game from [fanduel](https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/sports) using BeautifulSoup but I found (as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527338/scraping-fanduel-sportsbook-for-odds-with-beautiful-soup) did) that much of the data doesn't show up when I try something standard like

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get(<some url>)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

I know I can get do Dev Tools -> Network tab -> XHR to get a json with data the site is using, but I'm not able to find the same values I'm seeing in the HTML.

I'll give an example but it probably won't be good after a day since the page will be gone. Here's the page on lines for the [Rangers Dodgers game](https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/sports/event/1027510.3) tomorrow. You can click and see that (as of right now) the odds for the Dodgers at -1.5 are -146. I'd like to scrape that number (-146) but I can't find it anywhere in the json data.

Any idea how I can find that sort of thing either in the json or in the HTML? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you see the JSON in Dev tools -> Network -> XHR? I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I offered the solution to the reference link you have there. Those lines are there in the json, it's just in the "raw" form, so you need to calculate it out:

```
import requests

jsonData = requests.get('https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/cache/psevent/UK/1/false/1027510.3.json').json()
money_line = jsonData['eventmarketgroups'][0]['markets'][1]['selections']

def calc_spread_line(priceUp, priceDown, spread):
    if priceDown < priceUp:
        line = int((priceUp / priceDown) * 100)
        spread = spread*-1
    else:
        line = int((priceDown / priceUp) * -100)
    return line, spread


for each in money_line:
    priceUp = each['currentpriceup']
    priceDown = each['currentpricedown']

    team = each['name']
    spread = each['currenthandicap']
    line, spread = calc_spread_line(priceUp, priceDown, spread)
    print ('%s: %s %s' %(team, spread, line))
```

**Output:**

```
Texas Rangers: 1.5 122
Los Angeles Dodgers: -1.5 -146
```

Otherwise you could use selenium as suggested and parse the html that way. It would be less efficient though.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't even realize the line was a function of priceUp and priceDown. As for the selenium approach, I found that it gave some of the desired lines but not others. E.g. if the page had 20 different betting options (runline, 1st to score, home team hits, ...), it would only show the first option. Do you know why that might be? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening to you because some web pages loads the elements using java script, in which case the html source you receive using requests may not contain all the elements .You can check this by right-clicking on the page and selecting view source , if the data you require is in that source file you can parse it using Beautiful Soup otherwise in order to get dynamically loaded content I will suggest selenium

Comment: That's what confuses me--I'm able to see it in the HTML in view source but it's not showing up when I parse it with Beautiful Soup