# How to update FanDuel API for Men's college basketball

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I have the follow code that still works with what appears to be fanduel's old API for NBA data.

I need help finding how to edit the URL in the request of the following code to get men's NCAA basketball lines. I think that it would just require changing the event id from the current code which is 63747.

I have tried to inspect the site for the updated URL and event data but I am stumped.

Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# Scrapes all open markets from Fanduel for all open NBA events
# https://sbapi.nj.sportsbook.fanduel.com/api/content-managed-page?currencyCode=USD&exchangeLocale=en_US&includePrices=true&language=en&regionCode=NAMERICA&timezone=America%2FNew_York&_ak=FhMFpcPWXMeyZxOx&page=CUSTOM&customPageId=ncaab
url = f'https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/cache/psmg/UK/63747.3.json'
events = requests.get(url).json()['events']
eventIDs = [x['idfoevent'] for x in events]

scrape = []
for eID in eventIDs:
    url = f'https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/cache/psevent/UK/1/false/{eID}.json'
    payload = requests.get(url).json()
    if 'eventmarketgroups' in payload:
        for g in payload['eventmarketgroups']:
            if g['name'] == 'All':
                markets = g['markets']
                for m in markets:
                    event_name = m['eventname']
                    market_name = m['name']
                    selections = m['selections']
                    for s in selections:
                        selection_name = s['name']
                        selection_price = round((s['currentpriceup'] / s['currentpricedown']) + 1,2)
                        scrape.append([event_name,market_name,selection_name,selection_price])
df = pd.DataFrame(scrape,columns=['event_name','market_name','selection_name','selection_price'])
print(df)
# df.to_csv('Fanduel_scrape.csv')
```

Comment: try `https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/cache/psmg/UK/53474.3.json`. And then look at my solution from a few years back in the link below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping fanduel sportsbook for odds with Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527338/scraping-fanduel-sportsbook-for-odds-with-beautiful-soup)

Comment: Thank you very much. That answers the question.

Comment: @chitown88 any idea how to get an updated URL for CBB that includes New Jersey based teams? I got everything working but it appears that NJ cbb teams are excluded. The feed must be coming from Jersey? Thanks!